# Binding between two webcomponents: Google map + geo-localisation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to use the webcomponent google-map with the component geo-location like the third example on: 
http://ebidel.github.io/geo-location/components/geo-location/

**HTML:**

```
<geo-location latitude="{{lat}}" longitude="{{lng}}"></geo-location>
<google-map latitude="{{lat}}" longitude="{{lng}}" showcentermarker></google-map>
```

But my problem is, the {{lat}} and {{lng}} value are never updated for the google-map component in runtime.

**RUNTIME:**

```
<google-map fit="" showcentermarker="" latitude="{{lat}}" longitude="{{lng}}"></google-map>
<geo-location latitude="13" longitude="-73.57572912" watchpos=""></geo-location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are using the elements like this:

```
<body>
  <geo-location ...></geo-location>
  <google-map ...></google-map>
</body>
```

But declarative data bindings only work inside Polymer elements or if you surround them with `template is="auto-binding"`:

```
<body>
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <geo-location ...></geo-location>
    <google-map ...></google-map>
  </template>
</body>
```

See the ["Using the auto-binding template element"](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding) chapter in the documentation for more information on this.